# How to preserve client ip through a GCE ingress controller on kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've an gce ingress controller pointing to a service type `NodePort`.

Is there a way to preserve the client's ip?
I've tried this from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip), but it didn't work.

```
service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy = Local
```

I found some ways to do for nginx but none for an gce ingress.

Comment: Can you show your entire service spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original ip comes in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. If you're using rails it may come as `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/